# JQuery, cannot change the ID of a cloned element?

Tags: jquery

Is there an issue with updating ID's of cloned elements? I think my syntax is correct here but it's not updating.

```
function addQuestion(){
// Clone the first question Container and give it a new ID
$('#questionContainer0').clone().attr('id','questionContainer'+currentQuestion).appendTo('#questionArea');


// Assign the new ID to the text area field (This is not working)
$('#question0').attr('id','asdasd');
var test = $('#question0').attr('id');
alert(test);
}
```

Question0 is a child element (textarea) of the original cloned questionContainer0 (div)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
$('#question0').attr('id','asdasd');
```

to

```
$('#question0', '#questionContainer'+currentQuestion).attr('id','asdasd');
```

this would restrict your search inside the cloned elements only.

And to be more sure, you should do that before even appending the cloned elements in the DOM, since IDs are supposed to be unique in the DOM.

```
function addQuestion(){
// Clone the first question Container and give it a new ID
var newElement = $('#questionContainer0').clone().attr('id','questionContainer'+currentQuestion);
newElement.find('#question0').attr('id','asdasd');
newElement.appendTo('#questionArea');

}
```

Comment: Hi Gaby, thanks, so is the syntax you are showing allowing me to specify the parent element as the second param in the selector?

Comment: Hmm, still no dice - The form fields upon posting are all named question0.

Comment: I verified the questionContainer ID does in fact change, but the question0 does not. Are we sure that jQuery is cloning the ID of question0 each time?

Comment: @bob, do your elements also have a name attribute ? (*also with a value of **question0***) you would need to change that too, as the `name` is what gets submitted..

Comment: Gaby, thanks - after staring at it for some time I realized I was missing the name attributes.. doh!

Answer (score 2):

You're successfully changing the `id` attribute here:

```
$('#question0').attr('id','asdasd');
```

But then you try to access the element with the original (no longer existing) `id` in the next line:

```
var test = $('#question0').attr('id');
```

Could that be the problem?

Comment: It is indeed. I'll need to rethink this, as I need to only update the ID of the newly cloned element so I believe I need to navigate to the child element of the parent cloned and update it that way.

Found this post from 2009 that is similar to what I am trying to do: http://charlie.griefer.com/blog/2009/09/17/jquery-dynamically-adding-form-elements/

Answer (score 1):

Is your `alert` giving you `undefined`? This would be because you're selecting an element by Id, changing that Id, then using jQuery to look up the element by the *old* `id` (which returns an empty result set). `alert`ing the `id` of the first element in an empty result set will yield `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You change the id ($('#question0').attr('id','asdasd')), and then get the element with the old id ($('#question0').attr('id')), which no longer exists.